# Android Studio error pushing to Github

Tags: android-studio, github

Hello

I have a project in my Windows PC in Android Studio 2.3. I'm trying to Share my project on Github. I enabled the use of Git and use the Share Project on Github option, after that option successfully create a new Repository in my Github account but the initial push failed and states that it could not found the repository, and I'm checking the repository was created successfully... Any idea of what it is happening?

Comments:

1. Settings -> Version Control -> Github I checked the Test option and the host, Login and Password seems to be correctly.
2. Settings -> Version Control -> Git I checked the Test option and it seems to be correctly.

Comment: Have you provided correct login credentials? Have you set up the same for Android Studio?

Comment: Yes it is correctly setup actually android studio created the repository in to the account, why it could created the repository and said that can't push because it didn't find the repository

Comment: hi, I am facing same problem can you help me out of it?